# JFrame is not showing up even if I created an Object of the class and call it

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have this code sample. And I needed to change the background color of the `JFrame` when run the application.

But when I call the create a `object` of the `class` and call it with it's reference variable, the `JFrame` isn't showing up (**I think it is stucked or something**) I cannot even see the `java` icon in my taskbar.

Here's my code (Only the constructor of the class)

```
package lockme;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
        MainWindow m=new MainWindow();
        m.setSize(1368, 768);
        m.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(10, 20, 30));

    }
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
                MainWindow m=new MainWindow();
                m.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 40, 20));//This is not working
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
    }
```

`

But it shows the `JFrame` when I alter the code above like this:

```
package lockme;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
        //MainWindow m=new MainWindow();
        this.setSize(1368, 768);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(10, 20, 30));

    }
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
          //MainWindow m=new MainWindow();
          this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 40, 20));//This isworking
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd code shows the `JFrame` because this is the actual way it needs to be done.

In your 1st code, `MainWindow()` itself is a constructor whereas you are again calling another instance of `MainWindow` inside the same constructor which is completely wrong.

And guess what, you are calling the `MainWindow` again and again in its own constructor as it will work as infinite loop. That's why you stuck up there.

> A constructor in Java is a block of code similar to a method that’s
>   called when an instance of an object is created.

But you need not to create the instance of the object inside the own constructor of any class.

**Edit:**

There are several mistakes in your 1st code snippet. Let me clear those for you:

1. `MainWindow m=new MainWindow();` inside the constructor `MainWindow()`. It is totally illegal as I have mentioned earlier that it turns into an infinite loop.

   So, the correct way of doing this is mentioned in your 2nd code snippet.
   `this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(10, 20, 30));`

   **N.B.:** By declaring above line inside constructor means it will show that during runtime.
2. Inside `jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` method, you are calling another object of `MainWindow`. This will run the code well but will not work as you wanted. Look here you are creating another object of that class. But may be you didn't want this. Now let me clear this by example:

   Assume, at first in the constructor you have mentioned RED color in the `setBackground()` method. And then created another object of `MainWindow` inside `jButton2ActionPerformed()` and provided color BLUE as `setBackground()` . Now you run the program. The program initially runs well showing you the RED background colored Frame. But when you click on the button, guess what will happen. That red colored JFrame will remain as it is and as you are creating another instance of that class on button action, then after clicking on the button another new JFrame will appear having the color BLUE. And after you click the button for infinite no. of time, an infinite no. of new JFrame will be created. May be nobody wants that in any program unless any special case.

Comment: Okay thank you. But, Can I create an Object and call it in somewhere else? Like in a method? or inside a function of a Button?

Comment: But, how and where can I call the object of the class? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes, you can create an obect of class and call it in other methods. But think carefully, you are creating the object of a class inside any method of that class means you are creating another instance of the same class. So, generally we do not call constructor inside the same class unless we need to have duplicates of same class for any purpose. And inside any class, we can change the properties of any other objects without calling the constructor. As you have done in your 2nd code, using `this.setSize()`.

Comment: But this is not working. I need to change the background color when I click the `jButton2`. For this, I created an `object` of class **MainWindow** and set the color as usual. But when I click the button, no changes :(

Comment: The purpose of class based programming is the class works like a structure, then you can use that structure to produce a lot more of that type with same properties. So, now you can easily understand that where actually we call the object of class. For example, we call the object of `class A` in another `class B` to access the objects of `class A` from within `class B` and modify them accordingly, but actually nothing changes in the `class A` but all changes occur in the new object created inside `class B`. So, to do that we then write `A obj = new A()` inside `class B`.

Comment: Well, can you clarify more about your problem??? I guess you wanted one color during runtime and change it to other after button click. Am I correct??

Comment: Then How can I change the background color? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Yes Sir, I need one color at run time and next color when I click the button

Comment: OK, let me know one last thing, when you run the above code you mentioned, it is supposed to show background color but the button click would not work. So, can you see the color change in runtime or you are not getting any color change both during runtime as well as button click.

Comment: I can see the color change in runtime without any problem. But the problem is, I cannot see the color change when I click the button where I have created an Object of the **MainWindow**

Comment: This is because you didn't write any code inside `jButton2ActionPerformed()` method

Comment: But I can change the color if I alter the code with in `jButton2` to **this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.Red);** without creating an Object

Comment: No I have written the code, don't look up to the code I posted here

Comment: I didn't get you...and you have posted 2 same codes in your question..review this

Comment: It's OK..no problem. Well, but if the 2nd code works for you why do you need to do according to your 1st code. And if it is the case you need to know the reasons for learning, there are several mistakes in your 1st code. I will edit my answer soon and let me know after that if you have understood everything. As comments section cannot let me write unlimited no. of words so I am editing my answer there. Have some patience.

Comment: @CodingBeginner Now look at the edit and try to understand carefully if that helps you.

Comment: Yes I can totally understand what I have done wrong. But Sir, isn't there a way that I could change the background color without calling **this.** keyword? What if I wrote a `Thread` inside `jButton2`? then I cannot use **this.** to change background color because now **this.** will reference to the `Thread`. right? So, how can I do this?

Comment: Nice thinking. I appreciate your asking. Well, in that case you can omit **this.** safely. Actually the need of **this.** was not mandatory in your above code, too. `getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 40, 20));` should make it done. However, you have lot more options to do in this case. You can also use like this: `Container c = JFrame.getContentPane();
c.setBackground(new Color(100, 40, 20));` Again you have another option to do like this: `MainWindow.getContentPane().setBackground( new Color(100, 40, 20));`

Comment: Awww it works like a charm :) Thank you very much for the contribution

Answer (score 1):

That's because you get stuck in an infinite loop by creating a new object of MainWindow inside the constructor of MainWindow, essentially trying to create an infinite amount of new Frames.

Since you're already inside the constructor of MainWindow you don't need to instantiate MainWindow again.

Comment: But, how and where can I call the object of the class? Can you give me an example?

Comment: But I need to set the background color when I click a button. Even if I created an Object, it won't do the trick. Why is that?

Comment: im not sure I exactly understand your problem.

Comment: If you want to change the background after a button press just add the line : getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(10, 20, 30)); inside your actionperformed function

Comment: But this is not working. I need to change the background color when I click the `jButton2`. For this, I created an object of class **MainWindow** and set the color as usual. But when I click the button, no changes :(